# Quand doit-on utiliser « les » et « eux » - When should I use "les" and "eux"?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, pronoms

I'm in the process of localising a game<sup>1</sup> and I'm struggling with word choice in the following translation. Should I use "les" or "eux" and why?

> Your boosters can help you collect difficult shells. Use **them** wisely.
>   Vos boosters peuvent vous aider recueillir les coquilles difficiles. Utilisez-**les** avec sagesse.
>   Vos boosters peuvent vous aider recueillir les coquilles difficiles. Utilisez **eux** avec sagesse.

I think I should use "les", but I don't know why "eux" wouldn't work here.

---

*And I'll attempt a translation! Feel free to fix any errors.*

Je suis en train de traduire un jeu mais je me bats avec le choix de mot dans la traduction suivante. Dois-je utiliser « les » ou « eux » et pourquoi?

> Your boosters can help you collect difficult shells. Use **them** wisely.
>   Vos boosters peuvent vous aider recueillir les coquilles difficiles. Utilisez-**les** avec sagesse.
>   Vos boosters peuvent vous aider recueillir les coquilles difficiles. Utilisez **eux** avec sagesse.

Je pense que je devrais utiliser « les », mais je ne sais pas pourquoi le mot « eux » ne fonctionne pas ici.

<sub>1. Ultimately we plan to get the game localised by native speakers, but this seems like a great chance to practice some French and may help the translator!</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le pronom que tu veux est *les*.

Bien que la remarque de Reha soit pertinente, elle n'est pas entièrement correcte. *Eux* est avant tout un [*pronom disjoint*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphologie_du_pronom_personnel_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Pronom_conjoint_et_pronom_disjoint) employé lorsqu'il est précédé d'une préposition (par exemple dans *parlez-moi d'**eux***) ou dans une situation où il porte l'accent tonique (***Eux***, je ne peux pas les sentir).

Le seul cas où un inanimé ne prendra pas ce pronom, c'est lorsque l'emploi de *en* est possible. On dira donc toujours (par exemple) *grâce à eux* même si on parle d'objets,

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire dans l'avant dernière phrase.

Comment: Si la phrase employait *servir* au lieu de *utiliser*, on dirait normalement *Servez-vous d'eux* dans le cas de personnes, mais *servez-vous-en* si on parlait d'objets (parce que *de* provoque la possibilités d'utiliser *en*).

Comment: Ok, c'était pas clair.

Answer (score -1):

Dans ce contexte **eux** est un pronom personnel et servirait à désigner des individus tandis que **les** est indéfini.

Il faudrait donc utiliser : Utilisez-les avec sagesse.

Comment: Même avec des personnes il faut dire : « Utilisez-les avec sagesse. »

Comment: Exact autant pour moi, 'les' est indéfinis et non pas impersonnel.